# Samsung Corby 2 bluetooth 3.0 can't reconnect, "permission error 13"

Tags: bluetooth

**Samsung corby 2 Bluetooth 3.0 profile**

my phone has problem with reconnecting mobile broadband connection using bluetooth. when i connect to my mobile broadband connection profile in ubuntu, and when i disconnect that connection, and try to reconnect that again it shows network disconnected, and bluetooth permission error 13.

i have to turn off my mobile and then turn on to reconnect that connection profile!
 is there any way to reconnect using dun profile without restarting my phone?

PLEASE HELP ME!